# Insert another URL into WebSocket::EventMachine Iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, eventmachine

Let's say I have the following list of URLs:

```
urls = ['socket1.com', 'socket2.com']
```

I set up an EventMachine Iterator to open connections to those sockets

```
require 'websocket-eventmachine-client'

EM.run do
  EM::Iterator.new(urls, urls.size).each do |url, iterator|
    socket = WebSocket::EventMachine::Client.connect(uri: url)

    socket.onopen {puts "open #{url}"}
    socket.onmessage {|msg, type| puts msg}
    socket.onclose {|code, reason| puts "closed #{url}"}
  end
end
```

With that code I don't think I can add a connection to another URL if needs be.
What I need to be able to do is add another connection, to socket3.com for instance, whilst not affecting the other connections.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't think I can add a connection to another URL if needs be"? EM::Iterator will loop over the array `urls`, adding another url to the array will cause the Iterator to include that as well. Is there some extra code that better demonstrates how this will working?

Comment: Sorry, I've not been very clear. I meant once the Iterator is running another URL might come in that needs to be connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure an EM Iterator is the best tool for this, as you want to potentially add to the array whilst you're iterating over it, which doesn't sound very safe. From you're description, it sounds more like you need a pub/sub style queue that can respond when new URLs are added. Something like this might work (warning 100% untested!):

```rb
class EMCallbackQueue

  attr_accesor :callback

  def push(item)
    callback.call(item)
  end

end


require 'websocket-eventmachine-client'

EM.run do

  callback_queue = EMCallbackQueue.new

  # Assign a proc to the callback, this will called when a new url is pushed on the Queue
  callback_queue.callback = ->(url){ 
    socket = WebSocket::EventMachine::Client.connect(uri: url)
    socket.onopen {puts "open #{url}"}
    socket.onmessage {|msg, type| puts msg}

    # Maybe add to the callback queue from within a callback
    # based on the msg from the current connection
    callback_queue.push "additionsocket.com"

    socket.onclose {|code, reason| puts "closed #{url}"}
   }

   callback_queue.push "socket1.com"
   callback_queue.push "socket2.com"

end
```

`EMCallbackQueue` is simply a wrapper around the callback proc, when  new url is appended, the `callback` proc is called, and because it's all in eventmachine, the WebSocket::EventMachine::Client will process the url on the next tick of the reactor loop, allowing the rest of the code to run, which in turn will queue up more urls.

Comment: Works perfectly. I used a PeriodicTimer to check when new URLs needed to be added. Thanks!